# JS Fetch URL with redirection

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cors, fetch

I have a link A that redirects to a link B which is a PHP endpoint to download a text file. I was running the following code and it was working before:

```
const file = await fetch(linkA).then(res => res.text())
```

But lately, the server for link A stopped redirecting me to link B giving CORS error. but if I copy link A and paste it on the address bar, the browser will be redirected to link B and will start downloading the file immediately. And if I just change `linkA` with `linkB` directly in the code, I can download it without any CORS error, but in the app, I will only have Link A.

**So my question is**: can I get the link B programmatically before fetching it?

*I wished to share the links but they are private, unfortunately.*

**EDIT**

just to give more information. Link A is like an authentication endpoint, I need to pass username and password as query parameters. So the server authenticates it and redirects me to another endpoint (I believe that it's a temporary link) with the file I want to download which I can use in the `fetch` method without cors error.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that the server of link A only redirects me if I am from the same origin, so what I believe to be possible is to create a sort of silent window that navigate to link A `window.location.href` and after it gets redirected, I would need to block the file to not be downloaded automatically, get the link B and fetch it in the app... but I don't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: header params required is the thing here in CORS that shownup ?

Comment: @Codenewbie didn't follow your question. Do you mean the auth params or the HTTP header params?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to linkA server may have restricted it's access to same origin only.

And, if you are using using browser, it will work as you are directly hitting the URL which is technically same origin, but when you are using ajax call you are calling it from some different origin.

If you still want to use it seriously, then you can use cors anywhere. -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Comment: Yes, I tried to use cors-anywhere. I set up a heroku server to bypass it and it worked for the first time, but in the next calls, it blocked me with an NGINX internal error. I tried to workaround but couldn't get it working again.

Comment: You can try to pass either of these in options :
mode: "no-cors" or, pass header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

Comment: I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` error from NGINX even if I try it directly from the browser.

Comment: Should I use "no-cors" on the app or on the cors server?

Comment: Try directly on app with linkA. Basically it worked for me.

Comment: I tried both headers and didn't work. I always get this error: `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader`